# Why are there repeated Haftaras?

Tags: haftarah

Why are there Hafaras associated with more than one Parsha? Were there no other Hafaras related to the Parasha's content in such a way that there would be no need to repeat the same Hafara again during the year? I heard that Hachamim preferred not to repeat Haftorah, and found only one source be seen in שירים אארג – תורת הפרשה' (עמ' רטז) בשם הגר"א אולמן.

Comment: Can you give any examples? I know of haftarot that are used more than once a year, but the ones I can think of are used once for a parsha and a second time to mark a special shabbat / chag

Comment: Here is an example (there are more): Roni Akara, Haftarat Noach and Ki-Teze.

Comment: Not really. The haftarah of Ki Tetze is from Shmuel I 17 (as recorded in Rambam and as is the Italian custom). Roni Akara is the haftarah for the 5th shabbat following Tishah B'Av, which takes precedence (in Ashkenazi and Sefardi custom). So it's being used as a haftarah for a special shabat / time of year, not because of any connection to Ki Tetze.

Comment: @JoelK cool! Do we know how/when/where Sefardim went from the Rambam's "topical" list to the *shiva denechemta*? I never thought about that before, gee, why doesn't "David & Goliath" make the haftarah list someplace...

Comment: @Avi the others are behaalotcha and vayaqhel on chanukah and pekudei on sukkot. Always a second occurrence only for a special event.

Comment: @JoelK,, Thanks! But the question is still in its place. Even if the "repeated" Haftoras are in special occasions, could not Hachamim find other Haftoras sources related to the occasions with no need to repeat other "regular" Parashot Haftoras?

Comment: @Shalom. Rambam himself already writes that “the people are accustomed” to read the haftarot of consolation rather than the topical ones. More than that I don’t know

Comment: @DoubleAA And for Sefardim there is also Shemot and the first haftara of punishment

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What's the problem with repeated haftarot that you expect this not to happen?

Comment: @magicker72, I heard it and there is also a source that Hachamim preferred not to repeat Haftorah, see שירים אארג – תורת הפרשה' (עמ' רטז) בשם הגר"א אולמן

Comment: @Avi If you have reasons behind your question, please include them in the question itself.

Comment: @magicker72 There are no repeats in the regular sedarim (annual nor trieenial iirc) and no repeats in the "specials" (except purim meshulash but I don't know how old a practice that is), which does indicate that chazal or whoever was interested in keeping things varied. Why allow repeats across those categories?

Comment: @JoelK as Rabbi Berel Wein says -- *there were Sefardim before the Rambam too* ...

Comment: @DoubleAA Indeed, that's a more motivated question.

Comment: @DoubleAA Regarding the sedarim: Ofer's list has repititions: I see Is 46 שמעו אלי for ויהי כי זקן (Gen 27:1) and קדש לי כל בכור (Ex 13:1).